# Invoke-Command with credentials

Tags: c#, powershell

I am doing an Invoke Command method using powershell and I need to know how to input credentials into the script. For example at the moment I have:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 0.0.0.0 -ScriptBlock { Get-Command }
```

But I need to add Credentials all in one. I need it in a way it wont ask me to type in credentials, it just takes them from the script. Looking for something like this:

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 0.0.0.0 -ScriptBlock { Get-Command } -Credential username ,password
```

This is my context:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        if (RunRemotely == true) {
            richTextBox1.Text = RunScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName" + richTextBox3.Text + " -ScriptBlock { " + richTextBox2.Text + "} -Credential $cred");
        } else {
            richTextBox1.Text = RunScript(richTextBox2.Text);
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("\r\nError in script : {0}\r\n", error.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        if (RunRemotely == true) {
            $username = 'foo'
            $password = 'bar'
            $secpw = ConvertTo - SecureString $password - AsPlainText - Force
            $cred = New - Object** Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secpw)

            richTextBox1.Text = RunScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName" + richTextBox3.Text + " -ScriptBlock { " + richTextBox2.Text + "} -Credential $cred");
        } else {
            richTextBox1.Text = RunScript(richTextBox2.Text);
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        richTextBox1.Text += String.Format("\r\nError in script : {0}\r\n", error.Message);
    }
}
```

While doing this:

```bsh
$username = 'foo'
$password = 'bar'

$secpw = ConvertTo - SecureString $password - AsPlainText - Force
$cred = New - Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $secpw)
```

It says the name 'username' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: important i cant have a credential pop u

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes sorry wont do it next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Build a `PSCredential` object from username and password and pass that to the `-Credential` parameter.

```
$username = 'foo'
$password = 'bar'

$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred  = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secpw)

Invoke-Command ... -Credential $cred
```

Comment: I tried this but it says for everything it doesnt exist in current context

Comment: Hey i didnt explain what i am doing properly, I am doing this all in visual studio executing powershell through there So i need it all to be in one line

Comment: @IsaacLyne The code I posted is PowerShell, not C#, so it needs to be inside the `RunScript()` with the `Invoke-Command` statement. There are probably more elegant approaches to preparing a credential object in C# and *then* pass it to the PowerShell invocation, but I'm not familiar enough with C# to be of help there.